# At what moment is an object exactly "created"?

Tags: c++, memory, exception, constructor

Let's say we have some class with a constructor:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
    //our code goes here
    throw "OMG";//well, some code that throws an exception
    }
};
```

Now, when an exception occurs, stack unwinding is being performed. I also know that if the exception is thrown from the constructor, the corresponding object's destructor will *not* be called, because the object was never completely "created" in the first place.

I'm a little confused by this. To me that implies that the object is considered "created" only when the constructor finishes. But obviously, all the memory is allocated at some place before (or *right after*) the constructor is called, because we can manipulate the object's members inside the constructor.

So when exactly is the object created in memory, and what happens to the memory of an object that caused the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory is allocated before the body of the constructor.

If a constructor fails, the **automatically allocated** memory **is freed**.

<sub>And the accent of "automatically allocated" is important - if you have dynamically allocated memory in the constructor and the constructor fails (for example, you may have used `new` before `throw "OMG"`), this memory will leak.</sub>

<sub>That's because - you have allocated this memory, you need to free it.</sub>

You're right, that the destructor is not called, but the destructor is not the one, which frees the memory, allocated for the **auto** members of a class.
<sub>It's used (basically) to free memory, allocated *by the user* (in the constructor or somewhere else).</sub>

---

In other words, allocating memory for an object is different from the object's construction.

Another example - if you create an object dynamically, like:

```
MyObj* = new MyObj;
```

this will:

- call `operator new`
- then call the constructor of `MyObj`

See, both things are different.

Comment: It's before, but  not "right" before. Before the constructor body, the initialization list is processed and some members might get initialized.

Comment: Not only initialization list. If the class contains non-POD members, those too will get initialized even if they're not in the initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

*Memory allocation* and *object construction* are two separate things in C++. The compiler just makes sure that when thay're invoked together (which is the case with the regular - i.e., non-placement - `new` operator) and construction fails, the allocation is reverted.

Also, when the class has sub-objects (base classes and/or fields), the compiler invokes their constructors in a fixed order and makes sure than when one of them throws, the already-constructed sub-objects are disposed of properly (i.e., have their destructors called).

Answer (score 1):

The memory of the object is freed, but the destructor is not called (hence e.g. dynamically allocated pointers created within the constructor are not freed if you do not handle the exception in the constructor correctly). In C++11 the spec says that the destructor is called if and only if *one* constructor has completed entirely (relevant since a constructor can refer to another constructor).

Example (memory allocated by new int () is not freed):

```
struct Broken {
   int * i;
   Broken () {
      i = new int {5};
      OperationCausingException ();
   }

   ~Broken {
      delete i;
   }
}

try {
   Broken * b = new Broken {};
} catch (...) {
}
// memory leak: *b is freed, but b->i still exists
```

Comment: That's why you should not allocate memory in a throwing constructor -- or use smart pointers, which are exception-safe.